# Get current route's model in Ember component

Tags: ember.js

I'm writing a component in which I need to access the current route's model;
in the component's template I would like to do something like:

```
{{#each color in model}}
    ...
{{/each}}
```

I will use this component in different routes, with different models

How can I access the current route's model inside the component?

```
Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        console.log(this.get('controller')    //this is not the route's controller
        console.log(this.get('controller').get('model'));   //undefined of course
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass it into the component.

```
{{my-comp model=model foo=model bar=model}}
```

In the example above, within the scope of your component `model`, `foo`, and `bar` would be the model.

Comment: It was so simple! Thanks